# Prove that the empiric mean value has the lowest variance

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be uncorrelated random variables with $\mu \neq 0$ and $\sigma^2>0$.

Show that of all $T=\sum_i \alpha_iX_i$ with $\mathbb{E}(T) = \mu$ the sample mean $\bar{X}$ has the lowest variance.

---

I've already shown that
$$Var(\bar{X})=\sigma^2/n$$
$$Var(T) = \sum_i \alpha_i^2 \sigma^2$$
But it seems that it depends on $\alpha_i$ what's smaller, doesn't it? But I have no information about $\alpha_i$. Am I missing something?

Comment: You forgot the condition $E[T]=\mu$.

Comment: @angryavian Ah. I think I get it now. Because of that, it must hold that $\sum_i \alpha_i = 1 = \sum_i 1/n$. If I square the equation I get $(\alpha_1+...+\alpha_n)^2 = 1$. But since $(\alpha_1+...+\alpha_n)^2\leq \alpha_1^2+...+\alpha_n^2$, the sample mean is definitely a lower bound.

Comment: @angryavian It's clear to me now by using $(x_1+...+x_n)^2/n \leq x_1^2+...+x_n^2$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2774061/321264.